# Apache James relay setup

Tags: smtp, relay, james

I am new to Apache James and am trying to setup James as a server in between my application and an email server. I use James to change the attachments and then resend the new file to our email server.

I have been able to complete most part but have issues understanding how I can forward the emails to the email server from James. What config file would I need to update and what part of it.

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. It is done in the mailetcontainer.xml. There is a section for remote delivery. Just had to add the server name and port in the gateway tag.